# Wizard combat game on early online service

Tags: identify-this-game

Trying to remember the name of a game I played a couple of times, probably in the 1984-1990 timeframe.  It would have been on either CompuServe or GEnie - I don't think it was on a BBS, as I rarely  dialed into those, but I suppose there's a small chance I played this game on one of my rare BBS calls.

It was a multiplayer game where you played a spellcaster.  You chose from one of several specializations - I remember playing a Summoner who summoned monsters to attack the other players.  I seem to recall that the view was similar to Rogue-type games.  We were in a maze or walls or rooms.  But I don't remember now whether there were simple graphics or whether it was purely text.

Comment: Did you mean some kind of MUD? But usually they don't have roguelike view... And there were bazillion of them.

Comment: @selvin No, not a MUD.  This was purely combat.  No exploration.  I don't think there were even NPC monsters, or any sort item/inventory system.

Comment: this reminds me of [Lords of Chaos on ZXS](https://youtu.be/wkbwXZqaXLk) What computer you did playing on?

Comment: @Spektre It was a game on an online service, either CompuServe or GEnie (or, maybe, a BBS).  I happened to be dialed into it on either an Atari 800 or Amiga 500, but the game itself wasn't a native game.